# If $z=g(x, y)$ is defined by $f(x, y, z)=0$ near the point $(a, b, c)$, find $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} (a, b)$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, implicit-differentiation, implicit-function-theorem, implicit-function

**Problem**: Suppose $f=f(x, y, z): \mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuously differentiable, $f(a, b, c)=0$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(a, b, c)\neq0$. If $z=g(x, y)$ is defined by $f(x, y, z)=0$ near the point $(a, b, c)$, Show that $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(a, b)=-\frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a, b, c)}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(a, b, c)}$.

**My Question**: I don't believe the *Chain Rule* can be of any use here. By the *Implicit Function Theorem*, the $g(x, y)$ is indeed differentiable; but then how exactly do I establish the connection between $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$?

Any **HINT** would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Take the derivative of the identity $f(x,y,g(x,y))=0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $\hat g: N_r(a, b)\to\mathbb{R}^3$ by $\hat g(x, y)=(x, y, g(x, y))$, $h:N_r(a, b)\to\mathbb{R}$ by $h=f\circ \hat g$, where $N_r(a, b)$ is the neighborhood of $(a, b)$ such that $g$ exists and is differentiable.

Note $\hat g$ and $f$ are both differentiable on $N_r(a, b)$, thus $h$ is differentiable on $N_r(a, b)$. Now apply the chain rule.

Answer (score 0):

Let us define
$$
f(x, y, z) = z - g(x, y)
$$

Then
$$
f(x, y, z) = 0 \iff z = g(x, y)
$$

We find that
$$
{\partial f \over \partial x}(x,y,z) = - {\partial g \over \partial x}(x,y)
$$
$$
{\partial f \over \partial y}(x,y,z) = - {\partial g \over \partial y}(x,y)
$$
$$
{\partial f \over \partial z}(x,y,z) = 1
$$

Hence, it follows that
$$
{\partial f \over \partial x}(a, b, c) = -  {\partial g \over  \partial x}(a, b)
$$
$$
{\partial f \over \partial y}(a, b, c) = - {\partial g \over  \partial y}(a, b)
$$
$$
{\partial f \over \partial z}(a, b, c) = 1
$$

We note that
$$
-{ {\partial f \over \partial x}(a, b, c) \over
{\partial f \over \partial z}(a, b, c)} =  -{-  {\partial g \over  \partial x}(a, b) \over 1} = {\partial g \over \partial x}(a, b)
$$

Hence we have established the assertion.

Comment: I appreciate the answer! However, although I can see that $f(x, y, z)=0=z-g(x, y)$, to say that $f(x, y, z)=z-g(x, y)$ takes a leap of faith.

Comment: This is just wrong. You cannot redefine $f$ when it is the key player in the original set-up.